# How do I get my dishwasher running after replacing my kitchen faucet?

Tags: plumbing, appliances, dishwasher

After replacing my kitchen faucet my dishwasher will not fill with water.  The lights come on but there is no water.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

check to make sure the valve going to the dishwasher wasn't accidentally closed when you changed the faucet. Follow the flex pipe from the dishwasher to the valve and make sure the valve is open.